# Redis Keyspace channel not listening to SET commands

Tags: redis

I am new to Redis. Have enabled keyspace notification through Redis client using the command **CONFIG SET notify-keyspace-event KEgsh**, the output for **CONFIG GET notify-keyspace-events** is:

1. "notify-keyspace-events"
2. "gshKE"

The problem is except for the set event, the keyspace channel that is subscribed [using PSUBSCRIBE], is listening to all other events configured i.e. hset, hdel, del, etc.
I have verified that the correct channel is subscribed and the SET commands are also modifying the correct data in Redis. Also I confirmed this by configuring the notify-keyspace-events to listen to all events using the command **CONFIG SET notify-keyspace-event KEA** and noticed that now the channel is listening to set events also.
I am not able to figure out what could be the reason the channel not listening to only SET commands when configuring the keyspace events using the gshKE keywords, is there some configuration I need to change ? The Redis version checked through **INFO SERVER** -
redis_version:5.0.7

Thanks for your time. Any help is appreciated.